# Position Text to Stay in bottom right corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make the text stay in the bottom right corner, but once I change the window height or width, it goes out of the curve (shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl9fR.png))

I tried positioning it with percentages, vw, vh, em and [it still goes out of the curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ICa.png) when the screen size is changed.

Any idea on how to position this so it always stays inside that curve no matter the size of the screen?

Here is the code:

```css
.phone-number {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20vh;
  right: 5vh;
  color: #472d23;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

.landing-page {
  background: url("../img/bg2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.curve {
  background: url("../img/Curve.png");
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="carasoul" class="landing-page">
    <div class="curve">
      <div class="container">
        <h3 class="phone-number">+1 800-800-800</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Add Your Code Please.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added my code

Answer (score 2):

Try this. In HTML, add:

```
<div class="numBox">
    <p class="num">Your number or your stuff</p>
</div>
```

In CSS, add:

```
.numBox
    {position:relative;}
.num
    {position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to make the text stay in the circled part of the picture: http://i.imgur.com/MvnjaxQ.png but the problem is that on smaller screens, the number goes out of that circled area

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to set the text to fixed location relative to the bottom right corner:

```
.phone-number {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: #472d23;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 3vh;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want the text to stay inside the orange part of the curve: http://i.imgur.com/MvnjaxQ.png 
This works in a very small screen size only, but bigger screens, it is outside of the orange part of the curve.

Comment: Do you have the image somewhere accessible on internet?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Y68prLW.png
I want the text to stay positioned on the translucent orange part of the curve

Answer (score 0):

Wu. I think I my have a solution for you.

I think you will need a combination of things. Here goes...

**First**, I think you will need to set your position to relative.

**Second**, you will need to use a "transform: translate;" setting in your css, but use whatever percentages that you used before to keep the text where you wanted it. You would put those "y" and "x" percentages in the "translate" part of the css code.

Why do I think this would this work?

When you are creating a fullscreen video background for a webpage (or any kind of background for that matter), it is pretty common practice to use the "transform: translate" aspect of code to help insure that the background stays centered no matter what.

And if you think about it, what you're telling the CSS to do is to animate the item into the position you're telling it to be in, no matter the condition or size of the browser.

Using that concept, "transform: translate" should work no matter what position on the screen you want an item to have, whether it is to be centered or not. A really experienced engineer told me a few months ago that all engineering (coding included) is all about understanding CONCEPTS, because no two situations will call for the precise same answer. So the secret to learning is to learn how to adapt and apply concepts.

Sorry... tangent!

Anyway, I think that approach will work, even if I can't supply you exact code.

One more thing...

If "position: relative" doesn't work with what I told you, try "position: absolute".

I hope that helps!